# How can I set a task to execute at irregular intervals?

Tags: java

I have a task that I am attempting to schedule to run at 9:45, 12:45, and 3:00 on weekdays. I have tried using both ScheduledExecutorService and TimerTask, but both of these will only allow me to execute after a regular delay. I can't think of a way to get this to do what I want to do without creating 15 instances of TimerTask which are each set to execute once a week. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Yes, use a scheduler application appropriate for your platform, like [CHRON](http://www.rahul.net/raithel/MyBackPages/crontab.html) for UNIX or [Task Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Manager_(Windows)) for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the task so that after it finishes its work (or perhaps just as it starts work) it schedules a new instance of itself to run at the next time slot. At least that way there's only one task at a time (so to speak).

Answer (score 0):

I you don't mind introducing an external library then [quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org) will let you schedule tasks i this way (and a myriad of other ways also).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a full JEE server (Wildfly, Glassfish, WLS, etc.) you can use the [TimerService](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/TimerService.html) with the method [createTimer](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/TimerService.html#createTimer-java.util.Date-long-java.io.Serializable-).  Basically you setup the times you want to have the timer go off with an intervalDuration of 24 hours.